# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddMvc', 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseStaticFiles',

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have created .net core 2.0 mvc app using this command: 'dotnet new mvc' and it runs without any problems, but in vscode i have two errors:

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddMvc' and no extension method 'AddMvc' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'
>
> 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseStaticFiles' and no extension method 'UseStaticFiles' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) '

I'm using: Linux elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki, .net core 2.0, vscode 1.15.1.

Answer (score 3):

Your Nuget Restore could have failed when loading the project. Try running `dotnet restore` from the command line.

Also check to make sure you have `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` at the top of the file where you use `.AddMVC()` and `.UseStaticFiles()`

Comment: I already have it but still not working. CentOS 7 RH-SCL-DotNetCore-22. I'm following tuts here https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/ASP.NET-Core---Beginner/Dynamically-Rendered-HTML

Answer (score 1):

i got the same problem i fixed it by adding below package in .cproj file

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="3.1.7" />`

and did a `dotnet restore`. I am using `dotnet 3.1` version.